# How to loop through an array in react typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

How can I loop through an array to display the value?

Here is my following code:

```
  ineligiblePointsTableRows() {
    return this.state[PointsTableType.INELIGIBLE].contracts.map(contract => {
      return {
          applied: (<input
              value={0}
              disabled
              className="applied-pts-input"
          />),
          reason: (
            <div className="ineligible-reason-container">
              <i className="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              <p aria-label={contract.reason}>{contract.reason.map((reason: any, i: any) => (
                <text>Hello world</text>
              ))}</p>
            </div>
          ),
        },
      };
    });
  }
```

I got error at line `contract.reason.map`

> Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532) (parameter) contract:
> ContractUsage No quick fixes available

when I `console.log(contract.reaons)` this is the value:

```
Array(2)
0: "Cannot borrow usage this far in the future."
1: "Contract has a past due balance."
```

So my goal is i am trying to loop through contract.reason but I am having error like above. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Your error says that `contract` can be undefined. Have you tried to add  an undefined check to it? 
`contract?.reason.map`
of 
`if(contract !== undefined)contract.reason.map...`

Answer (score 1):

It's a typescript error telling you that the object might be "undefined", or in other words, might be empty of any value.

Few possible ways to solve this:

1.

```js
ineligiblePointsTableRows() {
    return this.state[PointsTableType.INELIGIBLE].contracts.map(contract => {
      return {
          applied: (<input
              value={0}
              disabled
              className="applied-pts-input"
          />),
          reason: (
            <div className="ineligible-reason-container">
              <i className="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              <p aria-label={contract?.reason}>{contract?.reason?.map((reason: any, i: any) => (
                <text>Hello world</text>
              ))}</p>
            </div>
          ),
        },
      };
    });
  }
```

2. 

```js
ineligiblePointsTableRows() {
    return this.state[PointsTableType.INELIGIBLE].contracts.map(contract => {
      return {
          applied: (<input
              value={0}
              disabled
              className="applied-pts-input"
          />),
          reason: (
            <div className="ineligible-reason-container">
              <i className="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
              {contract !== undefined && <p aria-label={contract.reason}>{contract.reason.map((reason: any, i: any) => (
                <text>Hello world</text>
              ))}</p>}
            </div>
          ),
        },
      };
    });
  }
```

Comment: After and question mark for contract and reason like `contract?.reason?.map...` I got error `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)`

Comment: Like the error says, it means that `reason` is of type string.
Can you share what the state looks like?

Answer (score 1):

It means that your `contract` or `contract.reason` is possibly undefined. To avoid the error use `optional chaining` like this:

`contract?.reason?.map`

Comment: After and question mark for contract and reason like contract?.reason?.map... I got error Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

Comment: It means that `reason` is actually a string.

Comment: Check the type of `reason` property